# assign multiple subnets to route table aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I think multiple people have asked the same question but my condition is different. I am taking input from the user for the vpc region, cidr value even the public subnet segment too. I have to attach all my public subnet to the default route table and private subnets to the diff route table . can you help me in how to attach them .

```
provider "aws" {
    region = var.region
}

resource "aws_vpc" "app_vpc" {
  cidr_block           = var.vpc_cidr
  enable_dns_support   = true
  enable_dns_hostnames = true
  tags = {
    Name = var.vpc_name
  }
}

# create igw
resource "aws_internet_gateway" "app_igw" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.app_vpc.id
}

data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {
  state = "available"
}

#provision public subnet
resource "aws_subnet" "public_subnet_01" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.app_vpc.id
  cidr_block = var.public_subnet_01
  availability_zone = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[0]
  tags = {
    Name = "public_subnet_01"
  }
  depends_on = [aws_vpc_dhcp_options_association.dns_resolver]
}
resource "aws_subnet" "public_subnet_02" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.app_vpc.id
  cidr_block = var.public_subnet_02
  availability_zone = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[1]
  tags = {
    Name = "public_subnet_02"
  }
  depends_on = [aws_vpc_dhcp_options_association.dns_resolver]
}
resource "aws_subnet" "public_subnet_03" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.app_vpc.id
  cidr_block = var.public_subnet_03
  availability_zone = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[2]
  tags = {
    Name = "public_subnet_03"
  }
  depends_on = [aws_vpc_dhcp_options_association.dns_resolver]
}

#default route table 
resource "aws_default_route_table" "default" {
  default_route_table_id = aws_vpc.app_vpc.default_route_table_id

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.app_igw.id
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "default_association_01" {
  subnet_id      = [aws_subnet.public_subnet_01.id, aws_subnet.public_subnet_02.id, aws_subnet.public_subnet_03.id]
  route_table_id = aws_vpc.app_vpc.default_route_table_id
}
```

I am getting error in adding multiple subnet so can u please help here :)

Comment: I can't see where the non-public Route Table is defined in that template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[aws_route_table_association](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/route_table_association) takes only **one subnet** as an input, not a list of subnets.

If you want to create the associations using your list, you can use [for_each](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#for_each-multiple-resource-instances-defined-by-a-map-or-set-of-strings):

```
resource "aws_route_table_association" "default_association_01" {

  for_each = toset([aws_subnet.public_subnet_01.id, aws_subnet.public_subnet_02.id, aws_subnet.public_subnet_03.id])  

  subnet_id      = each.key
  route_table_id = aws_vpc.app_vpc.default_route_table_id
}
```

The above assumes that everything else is correct. There could be still some errors in your code which aren't apparent yet.

Comment: Thank you for your response, i am getting below error    :   The "for_each" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined
until apply, so Terraform cannot predict how many instances will be created.
To work around this, use the -target argument to first apply only the
resources that the for_each depends on.

Comment: thank you for all the help but my code works fine if I declare rote  table association differently but when in for_each it gives target error :(

Comment: @AnkitSingh If you use `for_each` in one resource, other resources are usually also affected, because you have to reference  `aws_route_table_association` differently now, then before. So maybe this is why you see new erros?